# Get stream positioning c++

Tags: c++

I have the following task.

I need to check how many characters, words and rows, are in the file, that I'm opening. So I came to this problem.

When I need to position the get pointer, again in the beginning, it doesn't work. The `while((getline(f, charCount))`, just get passed away, it doesn't enter.

Here's the code:

```
void count(ifstream &f)
{
    int countChar = 0, countWord = 0, countRow = 0;
    string charCount;
    string wordCount;
    while (!f.eof())
    {
        f >> wordCount;
        countWord++;

    }
    cout << " Words : " << countWord << endl;
    f.seekg(ios::beg);
    while (getline(f, charCount))
    {
        countChar += charCount.length();
        countRow++;
    }

    cout << "Characters: " << countChar << endl;
    cout << "Rows : " << countRow << endl;
}
```

Comment: [`f.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of

```
while (!f.eof())
{
    f >> wordCount;
    countWord++;
}
```

is wrong.

It should be

```
while (f >> wordCount)
{
    countWord++;
}
```

Further reading: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Once EOF has reached, you'll need to clear the error flags of the stream before you can use it again.

```
f.clear();
f.seekg(ios::beg);
while (getline(f, charCount)) ...
```